# Use primary key or unique index for tag names?

Tags: sql, database, indexing, primary-key

I'm just wondering that, if I implemented a tags system, should I use a primary key on the tag name, or just have the usual primary key with a unique index on the tag name column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the tag entity will be used in millions of rows, a numeric column will perform better than a string as a foreign key column. This is *why* you use surrogate keys

So "just have the usual primary key with a unique index on the tag name column"

Comment: My primary keys happen to be UUIDs, though.

Comment: @rfw: And how wide do you expect your tags to be?

Comment: @rfw: don't use UUIDs for keys

Comment: @Andriy M: I don't expect my tags to be too wide, maybe about 25 characters at max.

Comment: @rfw: use tag name then: but expect a performance hit as you scale

Comment: @gbn: I don't think UUID keys are too disadvantageous, especially as I'll need replication and PostgreSQL supports UUIDs as a 128-bit integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two keys in a table then it makes no difference which one you make the "primary" key. What matters is how you intend to use them.